# Cannot bind ip to python socket on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2

I am running a simple python script with sockets on AWS EC2.
When binding the public ip I get an error telling me I cannot assign the requested address. And when using the private ip (tried it just to be sure) I don't get an error but can't connect either. Which ip am I supposed to use when running my script on AWS EC2?

```
# Open socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("<public ip>", 5000))
```

```
# Error when running the script
server_socket.bind(("<public_ip>", 5000))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: use the private IP and check that the security group allows the connection

Comment: note: most people bind to 0.0.0.0, for a good reason: then the program doesn't need to know what the IP is

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was the security group not allowing connections on port 5000 (now both the private ip and 0.0.0.0 work)